# MySQL Count based on date (group)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of problems solved only for latest date (which is 2019-02-16 in this case)

My query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE DIFFICULTY = 'High' ORDER BY dateadded DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

My table

```
dateadded      Difficulty
2019-02-02        Medium
2019-02-09        Medium
2019-02-09        Low
2019-02-16        High
2019-02-16        High
2019-02-16        Medium
```

My query should return 2   ... High+High from latest date-> 2019-02-16

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Nathalie

Comment: Your table appears to have no PRIMARY KEY. As such, it's not really a table - in a strict RDBMS sense. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, `dateadded` 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE `Difficulty` = 'High' 
GROUP BY `Difficulty`,`dateadded` 
ORDER BY `dateadded` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Will return:

`2, 2019-02-16`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the last date added:

```
select max(dateadded) from table1
```

To calculate the number of problems solved on the last date added:

```
select count(*)
from table1
where dateadded=(select max(dateadded) from table1) and difficulty='High'
```